# Can't access VirtualBox IP address from host using Bridged Adapter

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Windows Server 2008 on VirtualBox and using Bridged Adapter in the Network tab with my network card selected.

I open CMD inside the virtualbox and run ipconfig, I get the following

> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS suffix . : domain.name
>
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . : fe80::c75:ea73:aff7:92d4%11
>
> IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
>
> Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>
> Default Gateway . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

But when I tried to ping 192.168.1.5 from the host machine, I get Request timed out

Host machine's IP Address is 192.168.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Windows Server 2008 has ping replies disabled in its firewall. You should either [enable ping replies](https://patrickyong.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/enable-ping-replies-on-windows-server-2008/) or let ping replies blocked and continue to setup services you want and allow them in the firewall.